# How to change the IPv6 link local address of an interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ipv6

I want to remove the default IPv6 link-local address of an interface and want to replace it with a customized IPv6 link-local address?

Can you help me here?

If I assign a new link-local IPv6 address as below, then the interface shows two link-local IPv6 addresses. 
/sbin/ip -6 addr add  fe80::ade1:ac14:1334/64 dev eth0 scope link

I know below command can remove the old link-local IPv6 address, is there any other way to remove it without specifying the address?
sbin/ip -6 addr del   dev eth0.

Comment: Link-local addresses are automatically generated either by generating a random one or by using the MAC address, inverting bit 7 and adding ff:fe in the middle.

Comment: Please edit the question and explain **why** you'd like to change the link-local address without changing the MAC address. You'd be breaking part of the IPv6 protocol if you do so. If you want static additional link-local addresses, you can do so with ULAs, without having to remove the original link-local address.

Comment: This is just for a small experiment I am doing by disabling the DAD (Duplicate Address Detection). Since DAD is disabled, I want to assign a unique link-local IPv6 address by myself.

Comment: @dirkt No that is not true. LL addresses aren't tied to MAC addresses. Windows has never (since Vista!) really used MAC-based IPv6 addresses, but rather RFC 7217 addresses. It is a fallacy to assume EUI-64 is always valid for LL and assuming this will break stuff in the future. Also, routers in a segment are often set to `fe80::1` for simplicity. And that is totally okay to do!

Comment: One obvious use case: having stable addresses in protocols like babel (which only use link local addresses). `ip token` seems not to work in some places.

Answer (score -3):

IP address is mandatory for `ip -6 a del` command so you should write a small scipt to find out IPv/6 address. Original local link address contains MAC address of the interface in converted EUI-64 ID format what means the first byte's of the 7th bit of the MAC adsress is complemented.

Example:
`ip a show enp0s8` command output (unnecessary parts removed):

> enp0s8: ...
>
> link/ether **08:00:27:02:8a:41** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> inet6 fe80::**0a00:27**ff:fe**02:8a41**/64 scope link

EUI-64 ID: **08:00:27:***FFFE***:02:8a:41**

Converted EUI-64 ID, complement 7th bit: **08** (0000 1000) will **0a** (0000 1010)

From MAC adress you can construct the original local link IP and after you can use to delete this IPv6 address.

Comment: I can also use the getifaddrs() to get all the IP addresses assigned to the particular interface, filter out the IPv6 link-local address from the list and use it as an argument to the del command.  Just wanted to know if there is any simpler way to do this.